# PHP remove quotes around DOMText

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to append some HTML to the end of the body with PHP. I'm using a DOMText object and appending it like so:

```
$js = new DOMText("<script type='text/javascript'>\njson='".$response."';alert(json);</script>");
$bodyTags = $indexDOM->getElementsByTagName('body');
$bodyTags->item(0)->appendChild($js);
```

The problem is that the HTML I'm appending is being surrounded by quotation marks. Is there any way to remove those quotation marks or an alternative way that doesn't surround the text with quotes?

Comment: have you tried with DOMElement? http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should be using

`DOMNode` http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php or

`DOMElement` http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

to get the job done.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
$bodyTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');

$newEl = $doc->createElement('script');
$newEl->setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');

$response = "{'fname':'stackoverflow'}";
$js = new DOMText("json=\"".$response."\";alert(json);");
$newEl->appendChild($js);
$bodyTags->item(0)->appendChild($newEl);
```

There are several ways of achieving this. this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a javascript textNode object instead. That is what I usually use and it seems to work alright.